# using rails 3 mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email

How do you get the name part from the front field of an email using the new rails 3 mail ?

In actual email there is a from field like this :

```
<From: rogger rabbit <roggerrabbit@hotmail.com>>
```

If i do `mail.from.first` i get `roggerrabbit@hotmail.com` part but how do it get the name bit ie. rogger rabbit ?

thanks a lot
Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at mail-2.2.17/lib/mail/elements/address.rb i found this:

```
a = Address.new('Mikel Lindsaar (My email address) <mikel@test.lindsaar.net>')
a.format       #=> 'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net> (My email address)'
a.address      #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
a.display_name #=> 'Mikel Lindsaar'
a.local        #=> 'mikel'
a.domain       #=> 'test.lindsaar.net'
a.comments     #=> ['My email address']
a.to_s         #=> 'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net> (My email address)'
```

Try with something like mail[:from].addrs.collect {|a| a.display_name}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `decoded` method:

```
mail.from.first.decoded
```

Comment: tadman i get undefined method `decoded' for "regerrabbit@hotmail.com":String   when i do email.from.first.decoded ???

Comment: I was just looking through the [API documentation for Mail](http://rdoc.info/github/mikel/mail) in the hopes that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

After tearing my hair out all morning, I finally got this to work with:

```
message[:from].display_names.first
```

Where "message" is a mail object you might be iterating through.

Beware:  If the sender doesn't have a display name, this will be nil.